# rgbdslam: cannot connect to X server

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, turtlebot, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys:
I want to display PC A screen to PC B screen in `rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam`

how can I do......thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88486/rgbdslam:-cannot-connect-to-x-server/) by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably use ssh to start rgbdslam on pc A and want to see the window on pc B.
Try using ssh with the **-X** option, this will enable X forwarding.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-10-23**:
Thanks! I do it......but program did't respond........... how can I do

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-12-06**:
Sorry, but I do not understand your question.